# Comparing Date in Java String form with JDBC DATE type

Tags: java, date, jdbc, sqlmap

I need to define a SQL xml in ibatis where a date is being compared. The date which is compared is a DATE jdbc object and the date received from java object is a string. How should I convert string to date or how should I compare the two ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String format for both Java Date and SQL date could be different so comparing this String could be not a good idea.

```
        Date d = new Date();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
        Date javaDate = d;
        // Either get both java date and sql date to same format String and
        // compare
        String javaDateStr = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(javaDate);
        String sqlDateStr = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(sqlDate);
        System.out.println(javaDateStr);
        System.out.println(sqlDateStr);
        /*
         * Sysout console 
         * Apr 25, 2013 10:39:46 AM 
         * Apr 25, 2013 10:39:46 AM
         */
        // Do String compare
        // OR getMillis and compare
        long javaDateMillis = javaDate.getTime();
        long sqlDateMillis = sqlDate.getTime();

        System.out.println(javaDateMillis);
        System.out.println(sqlDateMillis);
        /*
         * Sysout console 
         * 1366866586716 
         * 1366866586716
         */
```

Comment: Thanks .But i guess my question is not very clear .I would state my question more clearly : in ibatis inline parameter map syntax "#propertyName:jdbcType#" , my property is a string object and JDBC type is DATE so the question is how can I compare the two ??